# Android: Search in ArrayList and show in ListView Via EditText ChangedListener?

Tags: android, listview, search, arraylist, android-listview

all description in screenshot.
i want search in arraylist use by (addTextChangedListener) and if found item, show in listView.
how to do write this method?

```js
txtSrch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //
   }
   
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
     int after) {
    //
    
   }
   
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //
    
   }
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will solve your problem:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: good way, but, if find several Similar  item ? how to AutoComplete?

Comment: example : `i am string AAA`  and  `i am string BB` ...   my text in editText : `i am`  ?? result ?

Comment: This widget gives you list with Strings contain typed characters and you need only pick (click) at this item.

Comment: If you type `i am` it will display list with `i am string AAA` and `i am string BB`, if you click on one of items, it will fill your editText.

Comment: what do you mean by "online refresh" ?

Comment: i want show result in listView. when `onTextChanged` changed. my listView result refreshing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82246/discussion-between-n1to-and-grizzly).

Comment: Resolved by showing code on chat how to add items to listview adapter in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to look only the same string, for example: if you type "a" it will not show anything, if you type "akron" it will display what you want, then you create method like this:

```
   public String myStr(String word){
for(String str:yourList){

if(word.equals(str)){
     return str;
    }

 }
 }
```

if you want to make it like if you type "a" and then to pop out"akron" you do the same, only you put startsWith() instead of equals() on on textChanged()

Comment: how to add listview row and online refresh list?

Comment: how to online refresh listView?